# Mocking a method does not return the value but executes the real method

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq

I am working on an application that gets a variable from an external application. I am trying to write a test using Moq but after doing the proper Setup and so on, when the ExecuteAction in the ExpectVariablevalue class calls the ExecuteAction in the GetVariable class, it does not return the value stated by the Mock, but tries to execute the code in it and (of course) crashes.

This is my test code:

```
[TestClass]
    public class ExpectVariableValueTests
    {
        ExpectVariableValue expectedVariableValue;
        
        Mock<IGetVariable> getVariableMock;

        [TestMethod]
        public void NumericValue_VariableHasTargetValue_TrueIsReturned()
        {
            getVariableMock = new Mock<IGetVariable>();
            getVariableMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAction(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<SimConnect>())).Returns(new ActionResult(null, "MyATCID", false));

            this.expectedVariableValue = new ExpectVariableValue("ATC ID", "MyATCID");

            var result = this.expectedVariableValue.ExecuteAction(null, null);

            result.Should().Be("True");
        }
    }
```

and this is my method in the ExpectVariableValue class:

```
 public virtual ActionResult ExecuteAction(object sender, SimConnect connection)
        {
            IGetVariable gv = new GetVariable(this.VariableName);

            var result = gv.ExecuteAction(sender, connection);

            string isExpectedValue = CheckIfVariableHasExpectedValue(sender, connection, result.ComputedResult);

            return new ActionResult(isExpectedValue, isExpectedValue, result.Error);
        }
```

This is part of the code on GetVariable.ExecuteAction. The crash is produced in the last line, as (obviously) 'connection' is null:

```
        public ActionResult ExecuteAction(object sender, SimConnect connection)
        {
            bool error = false;
            this.VariableValue = null;

            var returnResult = "";

            variable = new Variable().GetVariableInformation(this.VariableName);

            if (variable is not null && variable.Type is not null)
            {
                CommonEntities entities = new CommonEntities();

                var dataType = entities.VariableTypes[variable.Type];
                var defineID = entities.DefineIDs[variable.Type];
                var unit = variable.Unit;
                
                semaphore.WaitOne();

                if (variable.Type == "string")
                {
                    connection.AddToDataDefinition(defineID, this.VariableName, "", dataType, 0.0f, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_UNUSED);

........
```

I expect that once the line `var result = gv.ExecuteAction(sender, connection);` is reached, the mock return the ActionResult I have configured, but it just starts executing the code in gv.ExecuteAction

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

I have tried implementing an interface (as you can see) and several things but I have been stuck in it for days.

Comment: You are not using the mock anywhere. You need to inject the mock into your ExpectVariableValue class, e.g. by adding `IGetVariable` to the constructor of `ExpectVariableValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the GetVariable instance is being created inside the ExecuteAction method of ExpectVariableValue class, which is not being mocked. When the ExecuteAction method of the GetVariable class is called, it is actually executing the real method instead of the mocked one.

Modify the ExpectVariableValue class to take an instance of IGetVariable as a constructor parameter instead of creating a new instance inside the ExecuteAction method. This way, you can pass the mocked instance to the ExpectVariableValue class to ensure that the mocked method is called instead of the real one.

Modify the ExpectVariableValue class:

```
public class ExpectVariableValue
{
    private readonly string variableName;
    private readonly string expectedValue;
    private readonly IGetVariable getVariable;

    public ExpectVariableValue(string variableName, string expectedValue, IGetVariable getVariable)
    {
        this.variableName = variableName;
        this.expectedValue = expectedValue;
        this.getVariable = getVariable;
    }

    public virtual ActionResult ExecuteAction(object sender, SimConnect connection)
    {
        var result = getVariable.ExecuteAction(sender, connection);

        string isExpectedValue = CheckIfVariableHasExpectedValue(sender, connection, result.ComputedResult);

        return new ActionResult(isExpectedValue, isExpectedValue, result.Error);
    }
}
```

Modify the test to pass the mocked instance to the ExpectVariableValue class:

```
[TestClass]
public class ExpectVariableValueTests
{
    ExpectVariableValue expectedVariableValue;
    Mock<IGetVariable> getVariableMock;

    [TestMethod]
    public void NumericValue_VariableHasTargetValue_TrueIsReturned()
    {
        getVariableMock = new Mock<IGetVariable>();
        getVariableMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAction(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<SimConnect>())).Returns(new ActionResult(null, "MyATCID", false));

        this.expectedVariableValue = new ExpectVariableValue("ATC ID", "MyATCID", getVariableMock.Object);

        var result = this.expectedVariableValue.ExecuteAction(null, null);

        result.Should().Be("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could solve the issue!